# Dynamically creating new URL in Django base on counter

Tags: python, django

I created a website include 2 pages: index.html and status.html.
In index.html I create a new task and when I click execute the page move to status.

The page status.html is refreshed every 30 seconds and display csv table base other process.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', v.index),
    url(r'^execute', v.execute),
    url(r'^status', v.status, name='status'),
]
```

I want to run multiple task in the same time but the status.html page is the same page.

How can I create multiple tasks with other urls?

Comment: read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ask for dynamic parameter in your url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', v.index),
    url(r'^execute', v.execute),
    url(r'^status/<int:status_id>', v.status, name='status'),
]
```

And then you can access the `status_id` in your view:

```
def status(request, status_id):
    print(status_id)
```

read more: [URL dispatche](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: How can I change the url base on counter? Now I have this url: status/<int:status_id>